# How can I make hyperledger fabric idemix transaction in cli?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I have tried `peer chaincode query/invoke` with idemix msp folder(by changing the $CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH)  to set a transaction in fabric, but it keep failing.

So I would like to ask how to make a transaction in type of idemix in the cli docker-container?

BTW, I am using a fabric-ca in container too.

It would be very nice of you to be specific, thanks a lot!

Comment: set the environment variable `CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPTYPE=idemix`

Comment: @user1055010 Is it a newer function for fabric-tools after May?